# CSS Selector for an empty list disregarding white space or divs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have three lists:

```
<ul class="mighty-list" id="list1">
  <li>Cool</li>
  <li>Yah</li>
</ul>

<ul class="mighty-list" id="list2">
  <div id="floating_button"></div>
</ul>

<ul class="mighty-list" id="list3">
</ul>
```

Now i want to write an s there a way to select list2+list3 ( or select list 1 only) , considering they are empty of any `<li>` children?

I'm aware that the `:empty` solution none of the above because list3 contains white space, so i need a different solution to select list with `<li>` only

Comment: Fundamentally you cannot select based on content.

Comment: List 2 is invalid HTML. You can't have a div as a child of a ul.

Comment: With the in this case invalid HTML set aside, and as you already know, the `:empty` will work if there is no children, to select a list (assumed the `ul`) based on its child(ren) you need a parent selector, and they don't exist, yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way using jQuery.

You detect any `<li>` on the page and add a class to the parent. Then you can do what you want to that class in the CSS.

```js
$('li').parent().toggleClass('has-li', true);
```

```css
.has-li {
  /* your code here */
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mighty-list" id="list1">
  <li>Cool</li>
  <li>Yah</li>
</ul>

<ul class="mighty-list" id="list2">
  <div id="floating_button"></div>
</ul>

<ul class="mighty-list" id="list3">
</ul>
```